# How can I make Kerberos flush the credential cache when a user changes their password?

Tags: mac-osx, ldap, kerberos, mac-osx-server, opendirectory

We've got a fun new issue after upgrading to OS X 10.10 client and server with Open Directory (from 10.8).

When a user changes their password (using System Preferences or at the Login screen) it seems the Kerberos credentials do not refresh/flush/update. So when they expire, trying to renew them (after 10 hours) triggers our max failed attempts limit and locks the user out.

I can see that the **kcm** daemon is what is running after 10 hours that ultimately leads to the lockout.

I can see using **klist** that a password change does not update the credential.

And moreover cached credentials (within the 7 day window) seem to be causing this on *any* machine the user has used (our users move around a lot). So it wouldn't just be a matter of issuing **kdestroy** on the machine where the password changes.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Why was OD able to keep everything in sync across all machines in the directory before?

Do I just need to disable the credential cache? Was that not an an issue prior to 10.9?